# RegExp- How to match any 3 characters from a group of words/array

Tags: javascript, regex

My regex,

```
new RegExp("chicken|duck|kangaroo", 'gi')
```

How to turn "true" if the input matches any 3 characters inside the "pipe", or in between those group of words?

sample inputs:

> chi, luck, kang, chick, anga

I tried to do this :

> [chicken]|[duck]|[kangaroo]

but did not work.

Been reading about regex but still no success...Thank you for ur help.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use regex for this. Put the three words into an array and then check the inputs against each element of the array using something like `inputString.length >= 3 && arrayElement.includes(inputString)`.

Comment: Before showing your solution ("my regex") state the question. I'm afraid I don't understand what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "inside the pipe"? By "the input"? What do you want if `'gi'` were instead `'gcc'` (i.e., one letter appearing more than once)? Examples are helpful, but only if you show the desired result for each.

Comment: @88willr did this answer your question or are you fixed on passing in the inputs as 3 letters instead of the full words? I understand what you are trying to do, but it's easier to get matches the opposite way (as in my answer). Also, you could still pass in 3 letters and have each of these 3 letter combos in your regex. Not sure if order matters on the 3 letters? I assume it would. If not you can match just that at least 3 of the letters are matched out of order.

Answer (score 0):

Think it's usually the other way around. You pass in the full text like

```
chicken
```

or

```
duck
```

And your regex has the 3 characters that try to match. So your regex would be

```
chi|uck|ang|hic|ang
```

And will match when these 3 characters are found.

Does that make sense? You can try an online regex tester like [regextester.com](https://www.regextester.com/)
 to get a feel for what gets matched and what does not. It won't match duck on an input string of uck since the regex has more 'match criteria' than the input (the d is missing).